# Trying to execute a ruby file from Terminal but permission denied

Tags: ruby, terminal, permission-denied

So I was trying to execute a very simple ruby file that I saved in my user folder (by default) and I tried to execute it from Terminal (I am on the Yosemite version). After entering:

**#!/usr/bin/env ruby**
(then dragged the file to Terminal)

it gives me this:
**-bash: (file) Permission denied**

I have been looking that on the Internet and they said that I should unlock Root, I did so already but it still returns me the same denial.

I am very new in this things and would love to get some help! Smile | :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need the execute permission on the file `chmod +x my_file` to execute it.

**3 ways to execute a ruby script :**

If you're using bash:

`. my_file`

In any shell:

`./my_file`

`ruby my_file` (only this one doesn't require the `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`)

or just `my_file` if it's in your **PATH**

I think only the `./my_file` or `my_file` requires the execute permission, the others need the read permission only (try to be sure).

You can even pipe things into STDIN using `echo test |my_file` and putting this in my_file :

```
while line = $stdin.gets do
  print line
end
```